# Prove that an $AG(2, n)$ is never a 3-design (except in the trivial case $n=2$).

Tags: affine-geometry, combinatorial-designs

**My attempt:**

Consider $AG(2,n)$ with $n\geq 3$. We know that $AG(2,n)$ is a BIBD with parameters $(n^2,n^2+n, n+1,n,1)$ $\implies$ $b=n^2+n$. But for any t-design, $b=$ $\lambda {v\choose t}\over {k \choose t}$ = $(1) {n^2\choose 3} \over {n \choose 3}$ = $\frac{n(n^2-2)(n^2-1)}{(n-2)(n-1)}.$ Now, $n^2+n = \frac{n(n^2-2)(n^2-1)}{(n-2)(n-1)}$ $\implies$ $n=-1$ or $n=0$. But we said $n\geq3$, which implies that an $AG(2,n)$ is never a 3-design.

So I have a couple of concerns. Firstly, is what I did correct at all? I feel nervous about equating both the expressions for $b$ and reasoning from that. Secondly, I don't understand how we get a "trivial" 3-design for $n=2$. What does that mean?

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: And yes, this can also be used to prove the original claim (without looking at $b$ at all).

Comment: That would actually be much faster wouldn't it? If there exist three noncollinear points $\implies$ there's a least one triplet that doesn't appear in a block $\implies$ $AG(2,n)$ for $n>3$ can never be a 3-design. If $n=2$, then we have $t>k$ $\implies$ that if we let $\lambda=0$, we get a trivial 3-design be definition. Thanks for really fleshing out this question my friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is almost correct, except for the fact that you prematurely set $\lambda=1$; a general $3$-design may have different values for $\lambda$.

If you leave the $\lambda$ when equating the expressions for $b$, you can reduce your equation to
$$n-2=\lambda\cdot(n^2-2)$$
which has the unique integral solution $(n,\lambda)=(2,0)$, and this is in fact what's meant by "trivial" solution.